# sftp script to get a file from remote machine

Tags: shell-script, password, sftp

I use a script, which contains the line:

```
sftp    $FTP_USER@phcsftp.pearsoned.com:/dir/file.txt
```

When I run the script, it asks for my password:

```
user@phcsftp.pearsoned.com's password:
```

However, I don't want to be prompted to type my password.  I want my script automate the password entry and download the files

Guys, I don't want to do it. All I want to catch that prompt inside the script and put password. Is it possible?

sshpass belong to bash?

this is not working at all

Comment: Sometimes we don't have the option of setting up keys with 3rd party FTP sites. If you don't know, or you can't do it, you should just say so.

Answer (score 4):

SFTP is basically SSH + SFTP on the server side so what you need is some kind of non-interactive authentication such as private and public keys. Depending on OS you are using, you can generate a key using `ssh-keygen` and copy a public key to the server using `ssh-copy-id` command.

Answer (score 3):

The best simple way:

```
sshpass -p 'password123' scp -- $SSH_USER@phcsftp.pearsoned.com:/dir/file.txt /local/dir
```

`sshpass` must be work and for `sftp` too... Don't forget check permissions for script with writed password.

**UPD:** you need to install sshpass by command (for debian-based distro):

```
apt-get install sshpass
```

Comment: This can be insecure, as it will show your password to anyone able to have a look at the processes running on your machine. Key-based authentication or at least an expect script are better.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to automate this process is to use expect script. Here is an example:

for example:

```
  #!/usr/bin/expect -f

   spawn sftp ftpusername@phcsftp.pearsoned.com:/dir/file.txt
   expect "user@phcsftp.pearsoned.com's password :"
   send "mypassword123\r"
   send "exit\r"
```

You can get more info on expect from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or just google it

Answer (score 1):

You should use key-based authentication so you don't need a password in the first place.

Here's a detailed howto about how to do it:
http://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

Comment: Provided that the administrator of the machine allows subscribers to use key-based authentication.